# Error: oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment

Tags: r, cron, google-oauth, google-bigquery, httr

Using Shiny and R to create a little webapp that pulls data from Google BigQuery and spits it out onto the page. Uses the bigrquery package

When running the script from inside R (source(x.R)) everything runs fine, however when using Rscript x.R I get the error. I'm trying to setup cron to run the script automatically.

There is a .httr-oauth file in the directory of the script.

Comment: You are not in an interactive environment and `oauth_listener`, which presumably is used internally by a function you called, needs an interactive environment. See https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/R/oauth-listener.r

Comment: I realise that Roland, do you know how I can auth with GBQ otherwise? It's definitely doable as I have python scripts that do it flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to another one I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38301278/1007029) where I suggested using a Google Service Account for server-to-server authentication using the googleAuthR and bigQueryR packages for R. Please refer to that answer (via the above link) for details including an example R script.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've decided to just use python to pull data from bigquery and use it in R.