# How to authenticate with service account and bigrquery package?

Tags: r, authentication, server, google-bigquery

I have been able to authenticate using the json file associated with a service account using `googleAuth` and `bigQueryR`.

```
# Load Packages
global.packages <- c("bigQueryR", "googleAuthR")

### Apply require on the list of packages; load them quietly
lapply(global.packages, require, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE)

Sys.setenv("GCS_AUTH_FILE" = "json_file_location")

#Authenticate Google BQ
googleAuthR::gar_attach_auto_auth("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
                                  environment_var = "GCS_AUTH_FILE")
```

This works and I am able to start using functions from `bigQueryR`.

Now assume I am limited to the `bigrquery` package, how can I authenticate using a service account with this package?

I have looked at the documentation here to no avail:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/bigrquery.pdf

The resources I have come across on the internet propose using the 
`bigQueryR` package in place of `bigrquery`.

For instance this related stackoverflow question:
[Use bigrquery auth in shiny application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263003/use-bigrquery-auth-in-shiny-application).

But I need functions only available in `bigrquery`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`set_service_token()` is now deprecated.

Use `bq_auth()` instead:

```
bq_auth(path = "location_of_service_token.json")
```

Source: https://rdrr.io/cran/bigrquery/man/bigrquery-deprecated.html

Comment: When I provide the path to the JSON I still get a prompt "The bigrquery package is requesting access to your Google account. Enter '1' to start a new auth process or select a pre-authorized account." - I am trying to set it up so it requires no direct user intervention. Is this what is expected?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the function `set_service_token()`in `bigrquery` to authenticate with the same service JSON you use in `bigQueryR`

```
library(bigrquery)

set_service_token("location-of-service.json")
```

Source: https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues/22