# Authentication issue with R's bigrquery

Tags: r, bigrquery

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410147/how-to-authenticate-with-service-account-and-bigrquery-package) makes it clear that the function `bq_auth()` should be used to authenticate BigQuery in R. However, I have created a BigQuery-Admin service account, downloaded a service account key, and have passed that key into the `bq_auth()` function, yet I continue to receive the error:

```
> bigrquery::bq_auth(path = '/Users/nicholas/Downloads/just_downladed_this_key.json')
trying token_fetch()
trying credentials_service_account()
adding 'userinfo.email' scope
Error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/openssl/libs/openssl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/openssl/libs/openssl.so
  Reason: image not found
trying credentials_app_default()
file exists at ADC path: /Users/nicholas/.config/gcloud
Error: parse error: premature EOF

                     (right here) ------^

trying credentials_gce()
Error: argument is of length zero
trying credentials_byo_oauth()
Error: inherits(token, "Token2.0") is not TRUE
trying credentials_user_oauth2()
Gargle2.0 initialize
attempt from: bigrquery
adding 'userinfo.email' scope
loading token from the cache
Error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/openssl/libs/openssl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/openssl/libs/openssl.so
  Reason: image not found
```

It looks like I've got an openssl / libssl issue on my hands...

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the `openssl` library in R, and then rebooting R, did the trick. Running `options(gargle_quiet = FALSE)` to expose the logs of the error is what really did the trick tho, because it exposed the problem.